# How to get taxonomy in a div

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I want to add a taxonomy in my div with the different other fields, but I'm new to wordpress and O don't find how doing this, if someone can help me please ?

```html
<?php/* Template Name: Archive Projets */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'post_type'         => 'projects'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ):

        setup_postdata( $post );

        ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <div><?php the_field('url')?></div>
        <div><?php the_field('')?></div> /* HERE I WANT TAXONOMY */
      </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code that will get the taxonomies of the current post and display them in a list of  insert this code under *`<div><?php the_field('url')?></div>`*

```
// Get all terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , array( 'Taxonomy_name') );

// Dispaly the taxonomies, if there one or more.
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 echo '<div>' . $term->name . '</div></br>';
}
```

Make sure to change the 'Taxonomy_name' with your taxonomy name. let me know if I got you wrong or if you need any help with the code.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search brings up [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

foreach($terms as $current_term) {
    //You can now loop through them and get the ones you want, display them all, or whatever else it is you want to do.  Note: each $current_term is an object of type WP_Term (or error if there are no results).
}
```